# Remove cascade on delete from a single path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Follwing my data models. I stripped all the unimportant annotations to keep it short and clean.

```
public class Bubble
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BubbleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentLevel")]
    public int? LevelId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Level ParentLevel { get; set; }
    public Bubble Bubble { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LevelId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Level Level { get; set; }
}
```

If i create it like that i will get the error:

> 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Item_dbo.Level_LevelId' on table 'Item' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'

If i add this code the database creation works:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Level)
    .WithMany(l => l.Items)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.LevelId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But then i get this error when i delete a bubble:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Item_dbo.Level_LevelId". The conflict occurred in database "MvBubbles1", table "dbo.Item", column 'LevelId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

So i belive the problem is that Level is self referencing. Because i have many one to many relationships and cascade on delete works everywhere except between Level and Item, the only difference is that the parent is not self referencing in the cases that work. I belive i just have to remove one cascade path but at the moment i can't figure out how to do this and where exactly the problem is without disabling cascade on delete out right but i don't want to disable it.

Delete code:

```
db.Bubbles.Remove(bubble);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When there are more than two levels in references, database can not take care of cascade deletes, this is why you had to use `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`. After this if you try to delete something in upper levels, if it had a reference in two lower levels it raises error. I guess whenever you want to delete a bubble, first you must delete appropriate items from lower levels.

Comment: @TheGame402 add delete query to the question please!

Comment: Ok. Is there a function i can overwrite that gets called when i call
db.Bubbles.Remove(bubble);
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @TheGame402 Got it! before deleting any `Bubble`, you have to delete related items and levels first, otherwise you cannot! Can you give remote access with team viewer please so that I can write the complete code in your side.

Comment: Can't really post my TV ID + PW to the public.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't remove the Bubble while cascading is off, is because you still have Levels with a foreign key to the Bubble you want to remove.

Besides, suppose you want to Remove Bubble 2. Bubble 2 has a top Level 20.
Bubble 3 has a Level 21, which is a sub-level of Level 20.
Bubble 4 has a Level 22, which is a sub-level of Level 21.

If you remove Bubble 2, should it remove the Levels of Bubbles 3 and 4?

Let's assume that your software hasn't got these peculiarities: no circular Level references, and all Levels are from the same Bubble.

You could nullify all LevelIds of all Levels of the Bubble you want to remove before removing the Levels and the Bubbles:

```
// we want to remove Bubble 2
var levelsToRemove = dbContext.Levels.Where(level => level.BubbleId == 2).ToList();
// nullify all levelIds:
foreach (var levelToRemove in levelsToRemove)
{
    levelToRemove.LevelId = null;
}
// TODO: maybe we need an extra SaveChanges

// Remove the Levels and the Bubble:
dbContext.Levels.RemoveRange(levelsToRemove);

var bubbleToRemove = dbContext.Find(2); // TODO: exception if not found
dbContext.Bubbles.Remove(bubbleToRemove);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### A proper solution

The fact that your code has to prevent circular references and Bubbles with Levels that are sub-levels of Levels from other Bubbles, should give you an inkling that your database isn't normalized enough.

Consider to give your LevelCollection. This would be a one-to-zero-or-one relation, or if all Levels of Bubble 2 have several things in common, consider putting these things into a LevelCollection and let your Bubble have zero or more LevelCollections (one-to-many).

Every LevelCollection belongs to exactly one Bubble. The LevelCollection has zero or more Levels.

Now it is guaranteed that if LevelCollection 42 belongs to Bubble 2, that all Levels of LevelCollection 42 belong to Bubble 2. You can remove the foreign key BubbleId from the Level.

This won't prevent circular Level references, but it will prevent that Levels from one Tree belong to different bubbles

### Why cascading had to be switched off

Normally if you have a one-to-many relation like a School with his many Students, when you delete a School you also want to automatically delete all its Students. When cascading is on, then entity framework will first remove all items with a foreign key to the item you request to move before it removes your item.

This can't be done automatically with Bubbles and Levels

Let's Add some Bubbles and levels

```
                            Id | Name
Add Bubble with name A  =>  1  |  A

                                                  Id | BubbleId | LevelId
Add Level without Parent for Bubble 1         =>  10 |    1     |  null
Add sub Level of Level 10 Parent for Bubble 2 =>  11 |    1     |   10

Now give Level 10 a new LevelId               =>  10 |    1     |   11
```

Ok, cascading is on, let's remove Bubble 1.

Before entity framework can do that it has to remove everything that has a foreign key to Bubble 1.
So we need to remove Level 10 first, which we can't because we have to remove level 11 first. However, Level 11 can't be removed, because Level 10 can't be removed, etc

We have made a small circle, but you can imaging what would happen if you have a circle with 1000 Levels.

Your code will probably prevent that you create a circle, but entity framework can't prevent you to do this.

Another problem: Suppose Bubble 2 has a level 20. Level 20 is a sub level of level 21, and level 21 has a foreign key to Bubble 1. If you remove Bubble 1, what should happen with the Level of Bubble 2? Some people might say: it becomes a top level of Bubble 2, others might say: no, Bubble 2 loses his level. Entity Framework can't detect what you want, so you'll have to do this yourself and switch cascading off.

Comment: Took me a moment to fully understand what you try to say but i think i got it. I just thought it wouldn't be possible to have cross links because i never planned to have levels with parent levels that don't belong to the same bubble. I will do it the way you suggested with the LevelCollection. Thank you.

Comment: How will adding a LevelCollection prevent the same problem i had before?
I will still need to assosciate Levels with LevelCollections and you could still create a cross link from a level of one LevelCollection to a level of another LevelCollection. I don't even know if it's possible to get around this if i want to store hierarchical data in a database.

Comment: One of the problems is that not all Levels in a Level tree have to belong to the same Bubble. If Bubble A has an intermediate level in a Level Tree, and you remove Bubble A, what should be done with the Level Tree: suddenly the level tree of Bubble B changes? With the extra collection you are certain that all Levels in the Level tree belong to the same Bubble

Comment: I don't see why this would be the case.

Now every Level has a reference to the Bubble it belongs too but it could technically have a reference to a Level that itself references to another buble. (bad)

With LevelCollections every Level has a Reference to a LevelCollection and every LevelCollection has a Reference to a Bubble. The Level still can have a reference to another Level that is in a LevelCollection thast doesn't belong to the same Bubble. So the problem just moved one level deeper but it's still there.

What am i missing here?